# Normalizing and indexing SQLite database for faster query performance

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, indexing

I am currently using SQLite 3 alongside python to track and preform technical calculations on around 2000 tickers using their daily data. I have yet to properly normalize the database, mainly because it helps me visually when browsing the database in a DB browser to have most of the relationships in one table.

My database update time is currently in the 2 hour range, after deeper inspection I have found the main chunk of this time is not in calculations but in query time, as my update function needs to query the database a number of times during the update process.

I am currently using journal_mode=wal; so that I can read and write concurrently in SQLite, not sure if that has any performance implications.

Here is the current database schema:

```
sql_1 = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticker (
                                ticker text PRIMARY KEY,
                                name text,
                                sector text,
                                sub_sector text,
                                date_added timestamp
                            ); """


sql_2 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticker_prices (
                            date timestamp NOT NULL,
                            ticker text NOT NULL,
                            open real NOT NULL,
                            high real NOT NULL,
                            low real NOT NULL,
                            close real NOT NULL,
                            adjusted_close real NOT NULL,
                            volume integer NOT NULL,
                            dividend real NOT NULL,
                            split real NOT NULL,
                            ema5 real,
                            ema10 real,
                            ema20 real,
                            ema50 real,
                            sma100 real,
                            sma200 real,
                            bb_upper real,
                            bb_lower real,
                            rol_volume real,
                            vol_to_float real,             
                            PRIMARY KEY (date, ticker)
                            FOREIGN KEY (ticker) REFERENCES ticker (ticker)    
                        );"""


sql_3 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticker_technicals (
                            date timestamp NOT NULL,
                            ticker text NOT NULL,
                            ema5_slope real,
                            ema10_slope real,
                            ema20_slope real,
                            ema50_slope real,
                            sma100_slope real,
                            sma200_slope real,
                            ema5xema20 real,
                            ema10xema50 real,
                            ema50xsma100 real,
                            sma100xsma200 real,
                            bb_upper_x real,
                            bb_lower_x real,
                            rel_volume real,
                            gap real,
                            candle_shape text,
                            candle_size real,
                            candle_break real,
                            new_high_low real,
                            days real,
                            break_basing real,
                            break_trendline real,                             
                            PRIMARY KEY (date, ticker)
                            FOREIGN KEY (date, ticker) REFERENCES ticker_prices (date, ticker)    
                        );"""


sql_4 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticker_trends (
                            date timestamp NOT NULL,
                            ticker text NOT NULL,
                            depth real NOT NULL,
                            basing_point real NOT NULL,
                            slope real,
                            tolerance real,
                            point_2 timestamp,
                            point_3 timestamp,
                            PRIMARY KEY (date, ticker, depth)
                            FOREIGN KEY (ticker) REFERENCES ticker (ticker)
                        );"""
```

On average my database contains 20 years of data. The primary keys are timestamps, text, and in the case of ticker_trends table, real. ticker_trends table is the table that is mainly queried during the update process. ticker_prices and ticker_technicals have a date entry for every date the market is open, ticker_trends however does not.

Another though I had was to have two databases, one for all history and one for the last year if that has a significant change in performance.

Currently each db query can take as little as .005 seconds to as much as .5 seconds with around 10 queries per ticker.

Here is one of the slower queries.

```
            cursor.execute("SELECT date FROM ticker_trends WHERE ticker=? and depth = ? and date <= ? and NOT slope IS NULL ORDER BY date DESC",
                       (ticker[0], points[x], last_date))
        last = cursor.fetchone()
```

I have read about indexing but I am a little confused on how to go about optimizing this database. I am also not aware of how SQLite goes about querying timestamps as well as texts. I have thought about creating a unique id for each date in the database as well as each ticker and replacing the primary keys with int. If I do so is there a way to organize the database in some int order to help it query in less steps? Is there a way to have the database order it self by date and alphabetical order? Would this help? I appreciate any help as well as pointers to good tutorials.

Comment: SQLite is built for convenience, not performance.  If you need performance, then you REALLY need to discard SQLite and move to a real database server, like MySQL or Postgres.  Both are free.

Comment: This really was not helpful.

Comment: Then you may be in denial.  You have chosen the wrong tool for your task.  It's as simple as that.

Comment: Well then please elaborate.

Comment: If your primary goal is performance, then you should be using Postgres or MySQL.  Every tool has its target attributes.  SQLite targets simplicity and ease of use, not performance.